# Is there an example for a shell or computing accessibility culture aspiring a shell with more special characters and if so what is it?

Tags: shell, special-characters, syntax, historical-unix, accessibility

I was always a bit frustrated from the lack of characters in modern computer systems such as, from what I know:

- A *global template literal character* for which the closest character today is a backtick (`` ` ``)
- A *global quote character*, for which the closest character today is a single quote mark (`'`) or a double quote mark (`"`)
- A *global escaping character* for which the closest character today is backslash (`\`)
- *A global line break character*, for which the closest character today is a `LF` or `CR`
- Thinking about it, the entire regex language, on all its dialects, could have its own character system

I personally believe that such characters could make computing more accessible and at least intuitively would like to experiment in working this way.

I am aware that this would likely require to at least extend the QWERTY keyboard format and manufacture larger keyboards which I don't think will happen in the next 10 years, but I still want to ask on the **software side**:

Is there an example for a shell or computing accessibility culture aspiring a (Unix like) shell with more special characters and if so what is it?
Since the dawn of Unix and Linux, was there ever a discourse/culture about such a thing? What's worth reading? At least a name of a concept.

Comment: More characters make it *harder* to write correct software, at some point. (source code is different from human languages.) Hence, this is not a great idea. No, I don't think anyone would want that, and hence something like that is not in development. There's nearly 80 years of computer language theory that backs this decision. Basically, **very** simplified: languages being *context-free* (i.e. no character having different meanings in different contextes) doesn't allow you to write software that is omnipotent, but finite in length. Hence, trying to come closer to that  has little upsides.

Comment: Anyway, this is really a programming language design question, not a question about shells in particular, and not a question about Unix & Linux at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unrelated to Unix & Linux.

Comment: You'll want to look at a couple of the old, very dead, programming languages that actually *had* a lot of fancy special programming keys. Not a great idea in practice, even if backed by the largest computer companies of the day – [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols) is a good example of how to make it hard to write programs by using extra characters. You might also want to figure out what *character classes* are, e.g. in the 1970's TeX language processor. And then try to figure out why very few people think that this level of flexibility yields usable languages.

Comment: @MarcusMüller shells are very much on topic. This question is basically "is there a shell with $feature" and those are on topic. That said, I can't parse the sentence structure of the question. What does "which normally a backtick (\`) takes its place" mean? Lahor, can you please [edit] and clarify what you are looking for? All of these characters already exist and do different things. What is it that you are missing? Are you asking for imaginary shells supporting imaginary characters that would be found on an imaginary keyboard?

Comment: @terdon I agree, that's why I said "this isn't even about a shell". I think you need to read these bullet points as examples of what "normal" characters Lahor would want to replace with characters from a special *character class*. (The titular question is a bit misleading, I think. Shell doesn't mean "REPL program" here, but the shell scripting language, so it's really about the language, not the shell. It's a question about the existence of a scripting language.)

Comment: Hmm. Well, at the very least, I think we have conclusively demonstrated that the question is unclear, @MarcusMüller :) Lahor, as you can see, different people are reading this in diferent ways (although I suspect that Marcus's reading is correct) and it is likely that the question will be closed unless you can edit it to be clearer and/or more related to Unix and Linux.

Comment: Yep! Start by making your main question something that could potentially have an authorative answer that is useful to you. The question you're currently asking can only have two possible answers: "YES",  and "MAYBE", because nobody can prove that something is *not* being made by someone somewhere. But "MAYBE" is useless to you as an answer, and if the answer would be "YES", you would have actually wished you asked for "which (future) shell has the following features?" instead of what you're asking now.

Comment: Hello, I ask the community to give me some time to edit.

Comment: Don't worry, you can edit even if the question is closed (put on hold) and editing a closed question automatically puts it in a review queue to be reopened.

Comment: You mention "accessibility" in your edit. What kind of accessibility do you mean specifically with that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller just one example is backticks being very small and often hard to read and quoting symbols mish-mash in "long" one-liners (a very long `sed`?) For some, including myself, it's often an accessibility problem.

Comment: that is not a problem of your shell, but your font! You could have / create a font where these things are large and clear. The way characters are displayed has nothing to do with the shell, which only deals with the characters, not their visual representation!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't think it's practical to expect *anyone* to start changing shell windows and it would be more practical to find a much larger character (similar for brackets, for template literals). Furthermore, in the case of single versus double quote marks, it's not necessarily a font, in a one long-liner it can just be confusing, especially under much stress. Accessibility for the stressed is a legitimate part of accessibility.

Comment: So @terdon is this question going to be deleted now? What a waste.

Comment: No, it won't be deleted. As far as I know, questions with an accepted answer aren't deleted.

Comment: "_I don't think it's practical to expect anyone to start changing shell windows_" why not? I run my terminals at around 12pt but in occasion I drop them down to 9pt or increase them to 14pt. It entirely depends on what I'm doing in the particular window

Comment: You say that it's sometimes hard to spot backticks (or perhaps you sometimes confuse them with single quotes; I wasn't sure). Do you know that backticks are no longer recommended, and the correct construct is `$( ... )`? So ``x=`date` `` can more properly be written `x=$(date)`

Comment: @roaima I just work with the default, or change it once in 3 years. I just like to try to adjust myself to default in terminal windows. If I work in a team I don't want to change windows for other people. About backticks, I meant that it's often hard to see them, not about confusing them with single quotes; if there was a larger global character for template-literals, standard in generally all programming languages, I myself would have liked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there were attempts to create a system with its own set of characters to better describe algorithms. The most noticeable and successful was (and still is) - [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)), by IBM.
IBM even created a special keyboard for writing in it.

There is a [GNU APL](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/) implementation, but it looks like it is not part of any distribution and that there isn't much interest in the language.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apl